# Making IPython 3d scatter plot with highcharts

Tags: python, highcharts, interactive

I was playing a lot with the `python-highchart` package, following the excellent examples on this particular website

> http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/arnoutaertgeerts/python-highcharts/blob/master/Tutorial.ipynb.

Now I am a big fan of this way of visualization, however I'm facing difficulties to call from python / ipython (nbformat v4) to generate a scatterplot.

I was checking java example here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/

but I am failing to make this work:

```
data= [[1, 6, 5], [8, 7, 9], [1, 3, 4], [4, 6, 8]]
options = {
'title': {'text': 'Highchart 3D'},
'chart': {
        'renderTo': 'container',
        'margin': 100,
        'type': 'scatter',
        'options3d': {
            'enabled': 'true',
            'alpha': 10,
            'beta': 30,
            'depth': 250,
            'viewDistance': 5,

            'frame': {
                'bottom': { 'size': 1, 'color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)' },
                'back': { 'size': 1, 'color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.04)' },
                'side': { 'size': 1, 'color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.06)' }
            }
        }
    },
'plotOptions': {
    'scatter': {
        'dataLabels': {'enabled': True},
        'width':10,
        'height':10,
        'depth':10
    },
    'yAxis':{'min':0,'max':10},
    'zAxis':{'min':0,'max':10},
    'xAxis':{'min':0,'max':10},


}

charts.plot(data, options=options, show='inline')}
```

In the previous link, there is further functions and "var chart" reference, but as I not familiar with java at all (and only playing with Python for months) I really appreciate some help here to make this work.

Comment: Just a guess, since I'm not familiar with python-highcharts, but according to the docs, there should be: `data = [{ data: [[1, 6, 5], [8, 7, 9], [1, 3, 4], [4, 6, 8]] }]`. As for docs, see [`In [18]:`](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/arnoutaertgeerts/python-highcharts/blob/master/Tutorial.ipynb).